# How to start testing a RESTful web service using Java ?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

I have this web service `http://qa-takehome-creyzna.dev.aetion.com:4440` that I would like to test. I have the authentication details (username and password) and the service has the following end points: `/login, /user/, /user/{id} and /user/search`. For all endpoints other than /login an authorization token needs to be passed as an HTTP Header.

The service exposes a login endpoint ( /login) which takes a POST request with two parameters: username and password. Following a successful login, an authentication token will be returned which must be used to make additional requests to the service. For example,if the request is as following,

```
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin"
}
```

It may return `{ "token": "1234-0009-999" }` and this token will required for making additional request.

I will need to authenticate the web service, create 10 users and then, retrieve that information to validate the users was created correctly. I would like to develop a test plan and implement in Eclipse. How can I get started ?

Comment: Which level of testing do you want to implement? Unit, integration, system...? For definitions, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_testing

Comment: Take a look at REST assured (http://testdetective.com/rest-assured-framework-overview/) framework.

Comment: @Esko, I would like to do Unit testing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: @mlk, may be I'm little mistaken, however, what I would like to do is stated in the last paragraph of the question.

Answer (score 2):

A web service is basically an extension of the Java Servlet, where the input is processed a bit more and the output is rarely an HTML page.

Netbeans has an excellent tutorial on how to stand up a web service, and if you follow it, you can have a basic web service running within the hour.

https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-server/web-services.html

Don't be fooled by thinking that you must use one IDE (I like netbeans, but others don't) or another.  The fancy GUI tools are just writing plain Java classes that might use other plain Java facilities (like JAXB if using XML, etc).

A web service is not much more than a web server that accepts particular kinds of requests, and responds with particular kinds of responses.  In Java, web servers are made easier to use by leveraging Servlets.  The internal contents of the Servlet will look like

```
Unpack the request
Validate the request is complete, report an error response if not
Act on the reqeust
Generate a response in the appropriate format
Send the response back as the reply.
```

--- Edited in response to request ---

Sorry, It seemed too obvious to me.  Let me fill in the gaps.  Sorry for glossing over the details.

```
public class MockHttpServletRequest implements HttpServletRequest {
   @Override
   public String getAuthType() {
      throw new UnsupportedOpertationException("unexpected method use");
   }

   @Override
   public String getContextPath() {
      throw new UnsupportedOpertationException("unexpected method use");
   }

   ... repeat for all methods ....
}

public class ItemRequestWithBadEncoding extends MockHttpServletRequest {

   @Override
   public String getMethod() {
      return "GET";
   }

   @Override
   public String getHeader(String name) {
      if ("content-type".equals(name)) {
         return "text/plain-ish"; // this is not a mime-type
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("this mock doesn't support %s", name);
   }

   ... fill out the rest of the required request details ...
}

public class CapturingServletResponse implements HttpServletRespose {
   private final ArrayList<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<Cookie>();

   @Override
   public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
      cookies.add(cookie);
   }

   public List<Cookie> getCookies() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(cookies);
   }

   ... override other methods and capture them into per-instance fields
       with ability to return unmodifiable references or copies to them ...
}
```

Now back in the testing framework

```
@Test
public void testItemFetch() {
    try {
       MockRequest request= ItemRequestWithBadEncoding();
       CapturingServletResponse response = new CapturingServletResponse();

       Servlet itemRequestServlet = new ItemRequestServlet();
       itemRequestServlet.service(request, response);

       Assert.assertEquals("unexpected cookies in response", 0, response.getCookies().size());
       ... other asssertations ....
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Assert.assertFail(String.format("unexpected exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Depending on what items you care about, and how much work you need to put into it, you can then flesh out the needed parts of the capture and perhaps parameterize and refine the way you construct your input handling.

Comment: jeez old guy stop scaring the lad, i believe user just wants to know how to 'test' with 'java' not realizing a rest service (: +1 for the theory.

Comment: I haven't get an answer so for that is useful. How can I get started to write the mentioned test plan ?

Comment: @Arefe I gave an example to show you how you can unit test servlets without need for even a servlet container.  It's a bit of typing, but it is rather easy work.  Enjoy

Comment: @ Edwin Buck, thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. I have zero experience of testing and I would like to get started. 
1. Where should I put the URL informations and how to validate them using username and password ? 
2. Which framework you are using for this work ? I will probably go through their tutorials.
3. I understand that it's typing and may be pretty obvious for someone with many years of programming experience. What I would like to do I provided in the last para of the question. If possible, you may provide little more code for the learning purpose.

Comment: @Arefe For each Request you would want to unit test, you would write a new "mock" request by extending MockHttpServletRequest.  You put the various URL information and other items of interest in the class, just like regular Java code.  However, these classes represent specific situations and scenarios, so you hard code the data.  This will work with JUnit 4.x (no additional libraries need).  You basically capture the scenarios you care about, write "mock" (also known as fake) Requests, and verify that your servlet responds with the correct information (which is captured by "CapturingResponse".

Comment: @Arefe One last detail, the Mocks, Tests, and CapturingServletResponse are part of your "testing framework" and should go into your system in locations guaranteed not to ship or become part of your shipped product.  If using Maven, it would be somewhere under `src/test/java`.  If not using Maven, to be really certain, you might want to make a separate "testing project" that imports and uses the servlets built in your shipping project.  You might later "integration test" too, but that requires web servers, and web clients, and a lot of stuff that looks like a real deployment.

Comment: @Edwin, I see you are putting good effort to help me, however, I don't have good experience in all of them. It will be more helpful if you just write little more code of how can I validate the URL using username/ password and secondly, create and validate the information's of them.

Comment: @Arefe The best way to fix a lack of experience is to experiment with something.  If you don't feel comfortable experimenting with the code you have, write up a toy Servlet and experiment with that.  As far as testing validation, those answers depend heavily on what you are testing validation against (where are the credentials stored)?  In any case, you have a complete example above of servlet unit testing.  To write more code, I would need to know your servlet and exactly what your test plans are.  You know that, not me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103241/discussion-between-arefe-and-edwin-buck).

Answer (score -1):

Look into spring frameworks.
They go well with other testing frameworks like Mockito and Junits.
Use something like SpringMVCTest or SpringRestAssured, note RestAssured would let you write integration tests.

Read [this](http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/14/unit-testing-spring-mvc-controllers-with-rest-assured/) and [this](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: I have some experience with Spring MVC and Junit, so, may be this is better way to go. I will appreciate some sample code to get started. I mean, I have the url, how to use it for proceeding further ? I'm now looking to your provided links.

Comment: do you use maven?, if yes start a restassured poc and youll see how simple it is...it is also built upon springMVC, though i prefer writing my unit tests with Junit and Mockito and an integration suite with springmvc mock or restassured.

Comment: Yes, I use maven for developing backend with Spring, so, familiar with dependencies, XML formats and also, have some experience with Junit. However, I have never done any RESTful web service test before.

Comment: If you want to test the REST-Webservice with your Browser you must install an plugin.

If you use Google Chrome you can install REST Console 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

For Firefox install these REST-Client

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

REST CLient is also available for Safari http://restclient.net/

For Opera you can check out the Simple REST-Client

Comment: and for chrome don't forget POSTman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: Suggesting a framework to solve a problem is quite a bit of overhead.  Spring introduces a lot of tools primarily meant to solve IoC problems; and with some of those tools you can build a web service.  However, you can easily build a web service without Spring, and often it is easier than one thinks (as you are only solving the problem at hand)

Comment: @EdwinBuck Buck true but once set, the test suite or test project can run independently to verify the sanity/stability of web services provided. simple cron or even a scheduled job at some ci/cd server

Comment: @yUdoDis Testing web services are not unique to Spring.  In fact, with most testing suites, you don't complicate the testing configuration with a new Spring IoC weaving directive.  Cron should be running as a system service, should you need one internally, it's not going to work better or worse by being injected.  Mocks can be done quite easily, even without mock libraries, and CI / CD servers build non-Spring code every day.    If you don't need IoC, Spring is optional.  The cost of setting is up isn't trivial, and the overhead it uses can't be reclaimed.  Use when necessary.